# Inner Html Table Styling

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, styles

I am importing an HTML table (which does not possess id's) into my web app through angular. I want to style the table after I insert it into my HTML via `.innerHTML`. How can I add some styles to the table's `tr`, `td`, and `th` elements? So far any style I try to apply does not show on the innerHTML elements...

This is where I input the innerhtml:

```
const text = document.getElementById('text');
text.innerHTML = this.file.fileText;
```

And this is what the HTML for the table looks like:

```
<span> Sheet 0:  Gantt Chart Template<span> <br> <br><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><title>SheetJS Table Export</title></head><body><table id="excelTable"><tr><td rowspan="2" colspan="5" t="z" id="excelTable-A1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-F1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-G1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-H1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-I1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-J1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-K1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-L1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-M1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-N1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-O1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-P1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Q1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-R1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-S1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-T1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-U1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-V1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-W1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-X1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Y1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Z1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AA1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AB1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AC1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AD1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AE1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AF1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AG1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AH1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AI1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AJ1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AK1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AL1"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AM1"></td></tr><tr><td t="z" id="excelTable-F2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-G2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-H2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-I2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-J2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-K2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-L2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-M2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-N2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-O2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-P2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Q2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-R2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-S2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-T2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-U2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-V2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-W2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-X2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Y2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Z2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AA2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AB2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AC2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AD2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AE2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AF2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AG2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AH2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AI2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AJ2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AK2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AL2"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AM2"></td></tr><tr><td t="z" id="excelTable-A3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-B3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-C3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-D3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-E3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-F3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-G3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-H3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-I3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-J3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-K3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-L3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-M3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-N3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-O3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-P3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Q3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-R3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-S3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-T3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-U3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-V3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-W3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-X3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Y3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Z3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AA3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AB3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AC3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AD3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AE3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AF3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AG3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AH3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AI3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AJ3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AK3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AL3"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AM3"></td></tr><tr><td t="z" id="excelTable-A4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-B4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-C4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-D4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-E4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-F4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-G4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-H4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-I4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-J4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-K4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-L4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-M4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-N4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-O4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-P4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Q4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-R4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-S4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-T4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-U4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-V4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-W4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-X4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Y4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Z4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AA4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AB4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AC4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AD4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AE4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AF4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AG4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AH4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AI4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AJ4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AK4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AL4"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AM4"></td></tr><tr><td t="z" id="excelTable-A5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-B5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-C5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-D5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-E5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-F5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-G5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-H5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-I5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-J5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-K5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-L5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-M5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-N5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-O5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-P5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Q5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-R5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-S5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-T5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-U5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-V5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-W5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-X5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Y5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Z5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AA5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AB5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AC5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AD5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AE5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AF5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AG5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AH5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AI5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AJ5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AK5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AL5"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AM5"></td></tr><tr><td t="z" id="excelTable-A6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-B6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-C6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-D6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-E6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-F6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-G6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-H6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-I6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-J6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-K6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-L6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-M6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-N6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-O6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-P6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Q6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-R6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-S6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-T6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-U6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-V6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-W6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-X6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Y6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Z6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AA6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AB6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AC6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AD6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AE6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AF6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AG6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AH6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AI6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AJ6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AK6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AL6"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AM6"></td></tr><tr><td t="z" id="excelTable-A7"></td><td t="s" id="excelTable-B7" v="Task Name">Task Name</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-C7" v="Start(Date)">Start(Date)</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-D7" v="End  (Date)">End  (Date)</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-E7" v="Duration (Days)">Duration (Days)</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-F7" v="Task Name">Task Name</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-G7" v="Start  (Date)">Start  (Date)</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-H7" v="End  (Date)">End  (Date)</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-I7" v="Duration (Days)">Duration (Days)</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-J7" v="Task Name">Task Name</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-K7" v="Start  (Date)">Start  (Date)</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-L7" v="End  (Date)">End  (Date)</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-M7" v="Duration (Days)">Duration (Days)</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-N7" v="Task Name">Task Name</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-O7" v="Start  (Date)">Start  (Date)</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-P7" v="End  (Date)">End  (Date)</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-Q7" v="Duration (Days)">Duration (Days)</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-R7" v="Task Name">Task Name</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-S7" v="Start  (Date)">Start  (Date)</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-T7" v="End  (Date)">End  (Date)</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-U7" v="Duration (Days)">Duration (Days)</td><td t="z" id="excelTable-V7"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-W7"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-X7"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Y7"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Z7"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AA7"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AB7"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AC7"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AD7"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AE7"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AF7"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AG7"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AH7"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AI7"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AJ7"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AK7"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AL7"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AM7"></td></tr><tr><td t="z" id="excelTable-A8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-B8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-C8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-D8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-E8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-F8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-G8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-H8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-I8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-J8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-K8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-L8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-M8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-N8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-O8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-P8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Q8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-R8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-S8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-T8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-U8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-V8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-W8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-X8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Y8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Z8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AA8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AB8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AC8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AD8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AE8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AF8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AG8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AH8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AI8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AJ8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AK8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AL8"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AM8"></td></tr><tr><td t="z" id="excelTable-A9"></td><td t="s" id="excelTable-B9" v="Evironment Set-up/Learn SAAVIE">Evironment Set-up/Learn SAAVIE</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-C9" v="44334">44334</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-D9" v="44347">44347</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-E9" v="13">13</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-F9" v="Evironment Set-up/Learn SAAVIE">Evironment Set-up/Learn SAAVIE</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-G9" v="44334">44334</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-H9" v="44347">44347</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-I9" v="13">13</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-J9" v="Evironment Set-up/Learn SAAVIE">Evironment Set-up/Learn SAAVIE</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-K9" v="44334">44334</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-L9" v="44347">44347</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-M9" v="13">13</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-N9" v="Evironment Set-up/Learn SAAVIE">Evironment Set-up/Learn SAAVIE</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-O9" v="44334">44334</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-P9" v="44347">44347</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-Q9" v="13">13</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-R9" v="Evironment Set-up/Learn SAAVIE">Evironment Set-up/Learn SAAVIE</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-S9" v="44334">44334</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-T9" v="44347">44347</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-U9" v="13">13</td><td t="z" id="excelTable-V9"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-W9"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-X9"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Y9"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Z9"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AA9"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AB9"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AC9"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AD9"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AE9"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AF9"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AG9"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AH9"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AI9"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AJ9"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AK9"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AL9"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AM9"></td></tr><tr><td t="z" id="excelTable-A10"></td><td t="s" id="excelTable-B10" v="Angular Tutorials">Angular Tutorials</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-C10" v="44336">44336</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-D10" v="44349">44349</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-E10" v="13">13</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-F10" v="Angular Tutorials">Angular Tutorials</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-G10" v="44336">44336</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-H10" v="44349">44349</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-I10" v="13">13</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-J10" v="Angular Tutorials">Angular Tutorials</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-K10" v="44336">44336</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-L10" v="44349">44349</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-M10" v="13">13</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-N10" v="Angular Tutorials">Angular Tutorials</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-O10" v="44336">44336</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-P10" v="44349">44349</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-Q10" v="13">13</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-R10" v="Angular Tutorials">Angular Tutorials</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-S10" v="44336">44336</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-T10" v="44349">44349</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-U10" v="13">13</td><td t="z" id="excelTable-V10"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-W10"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-X10"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Y10"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Z10"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AA10"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AB10"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AC10"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AD10"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AE10"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AF10"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AG10"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AH10"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AI10"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AJ10"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AK10"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AL10"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AM10"></td></tr><tr><td t="z" id="excelTable-A11"></td><td t="s" id="excelTable-B11" v="Design Mock UI's">Design Mock UI&apos;s</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-C11" v="44348">44348</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-D11" v="44353">44353</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-E11" v="5">5</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-F11" v="Design Mock UI's">Design Mock UI&apos;s</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-G11" v="44348">44348</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-H11" v="44353">44353</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-I11" v="5">5</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-J11" v="Design Mock UI's">Design Mock UI&apos;s</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-K11" v="44348">44348</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-L11" v="44353">44353</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-M11" v="5">5</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-N11" v="Design Mock UI's">Design Mock UI&apos;s</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-O11" v="44348">44348</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-P11" v="44353">44353</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-Q11" v="5">5</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-R11" v="Design Mock UI's">Design Mock UI&apos;s</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-S11" v="44348">44348</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-T11" v="44353">44353</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-U11" v="5">5</td><td t="z" id="excelTable-V11"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-W11"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-X11"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Y11"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Z11"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AA11"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AB11"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AC11"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AD11"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AE11"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AF11"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AG11"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AH11"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AI11"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AJ11"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AK11"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AL11"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AM11"></td></tr><tr><td t="z" id="excelTable-A12"></td><td t="s" id="excelTable-B12" v="Create Elementary Tab">Create Elementary Tab</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-C12" v="44349">44349</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-D12" v="44357">44357</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-E12" v="8">8</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-F12" v="Create Elementary Tab">Create Elementary Tab</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-G12" v="44349">44349</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-H12" v="44357">44357</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-I12" v="8">8</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-J12" v="Create Elementary Tab">Create Elementary Tab</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-K12" v="44349">44349</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-L12" v="44357">44357</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-M12" v="8">8</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-N12" v="Create Elementary Tab">Create Elementary Tab</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-O12" v="44349">44349</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-P12" v="44357">44357</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-Q12" v="8">8</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-R12" v="Create Elementary Tab">Create Elementary Tab</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-S12" v="44349">44349</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-T12" v="44357">44357</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-U12" v="8">8</td><td t="z" id="excelTable-V12"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-W12"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-X12"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Y12"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Z12"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AA12"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AB12"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AC12"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AD12"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AE12"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AF12"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AG12"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AH12"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AI12"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AJ12"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AK12"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AL12"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AM12"></td></tr><tr><td t="z" id="excelTable-A13"></td><td t="s" id="excelTable-B13" v="Create Recent Imports Tab">Create Recent Imports Tab</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-C13" v="44357">44357</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-D13" v="44364">44364</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-E13" v="7">7</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-F13" v="Create Recent Imports Tab">Create Recent Imports Tab</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-G13" v="44357">44357</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-H13" v="44364">44364</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-I13" v="7">7</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-J13" v="Create Recent Imports Tab">Create Recent Imports Tab</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-K13" v="44357">44357</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-L13" v="44364">44364</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-M13" v="7">7</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-N13" v="Create Recent Imports Tab">Create Recent Imports Tab</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-O13" v="44357">44357</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-P13" v="44364">44364</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-Q13" v="7">7</td><td t="s" id="excelTable-R13" v="Create Recent Imports Tab">Create Recent Imports Tab</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-S13" v="44357">44357</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-T13" v="44364">44364</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-U13" v="7">7</td><td t="z" id="excelTable-V13"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-W13"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-X13"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Y13"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Z13"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AA13"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AB13"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AC13"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AD13"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AE13"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AF13"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AG13"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AH13"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AI13"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AJ13"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AK13"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AL13"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AM13"></td></tr><tr><td t="z" id="excelTable-A14"></td><td t="s" id="excelTable-B14" v="Add Media File Functionality">Add Media File Functionality</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-C14" v="44357">44357</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-D14" v="44361">44361</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-E14" v="4">4</td><td t="z" id="excelTable-F14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-G14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-H14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-I14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-J14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-K14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-L14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-M14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-N14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-O14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-P14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Q14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-R14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-S14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-T14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-U14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-V14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-W14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-X14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Y14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Z14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AA14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AB14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AC14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AD14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AE14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AF14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AG14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AH14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AI14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AJ14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AK14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AL14"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AM14"></td></tr><tr><td t="z" id="excelTable-A15"></td><td t="s" id="excelTable-B15" v="Find/Integrate Sample Data">Find/Integrate Sample Data</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-C15" v="44364">44364</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-D15" v="44372">44372</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-E15" v="8">8</td><td t="z" id="excelTable-F15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-G15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-H15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-I15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-J15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-K15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-L15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-M15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-N15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-O15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-P15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Q15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-R15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-S15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-T15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-U15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-V15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-W15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-X15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Y15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Z15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AA15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AB15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AC15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AD15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AE15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AF15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AG15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AH15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AI15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AJ15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AK15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AL15"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AM15"></td></tr><tr><td t="z" id="excelTable-A16"></td><td t="s" id="excelTable-B16" v="Globe Visualization Feature">Globe Visualization Feature</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-C16" v="44372">44372</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-D16" v="44379">44379</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-E16" v="7">7</td><td t="z" id="excelTable-F16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-G16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-H16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-I16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-J16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-K16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-L16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-M16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-N16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-O16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-P16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Q16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-R16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-S16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-T16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-U16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-V16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-W16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-X16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Y16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Z16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AA16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AB16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AC16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AD16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AE16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AF16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AG16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AH16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AI16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AJ16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AK16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AL16"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AM16"></td></tr><tr><td t="z" id="excelTable-A17"></td><td t="s" id="excelTable-B17" v="Refine Solutions">Refine Solutions</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-C17" v="44377">44377</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-D17" v="44385">44385</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-E17" v="8">8</td><td t="z" id="excelTable-F17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-G17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-H17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-I17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-J17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-K17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-L17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-M17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-N17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-O17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-P17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Q17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-R17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-S17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-T17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-U17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-V17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-W17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-X17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Y17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Z17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AA17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AB17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AC17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AD17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AE17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AF17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AG17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AH17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AI17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AJ17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AK17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AL17"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AM17"></td></tr><tr><td t="z" id="excelTable-A18"></td><td t="s" id="excelTable-B18" v="Workspace Integration">Workspace Integration</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-C18" v="44383">44383</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-D18" v="44397">44397</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-E18" v="14">14</td><td t="z" id="excelTable-F18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-G18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-H18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-I18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-J18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-K18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-L18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-M18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-N18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-O18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-P18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Q18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-R18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-S18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-T18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-U18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-V18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-W18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-X18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Y18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Z18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AA18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AB18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AC18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AD18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AE18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AF18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AG18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AH18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AI18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AJ18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AK18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AL18"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AM18"></td></tr><tr><td t="z" id="excelTable-A19"></td><td t="s" id="excelTable-B19" v="Documentation/Clean Code">Documentation/Clean Code</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-C19" v="44397">44397</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-D19" v="44413">44413</td><td t="n" id="excelTable-E19" v="16">16</td><td t="z" id="excelTable-F19"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-G19"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-H19"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-I19"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-J19"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-K19"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-L19"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-M19"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-N19"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-O19"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-P19"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Q19"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-R19"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-S19"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-T19"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-U19"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-V19"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-W19"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-X19"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Y19"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-Z19"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AA19"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AB19"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AC19"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AD19"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AE19"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AF19"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AG19"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AH19"></td><td t="z" id="excelTable-AI19"></td></table></body></html>
```

This is the html element I add my table to:

```
<div id="text" class='excel'> </div>
```

... when I try and use `td {}` or `tr {}` etc. to style or even

```
[id^='excelTable'] {
border: 1px solid #dddddd;
text-align: left;
padding: 8px;}
```

none of the stylings are shown...

Comment: Add classes to the elements and use CSS to style.  Don't use innerHTML for styling.  If you insist on using innerHTML, we need to see your code segment.  We have absolutely no idea why it's not working if we can't see your code.

Comment: just added my code

Comment: We need to see the HTML element with id = 'text'.  We also need to know the value of `this.file.fileText`.  Please `console.log(this.file.fileText);` to verify the value and update your question with the results.

Comment: The value of this.file.fileText is the table html

Comment: So, at this point, I'm going to suggest you read about [how to provide a minimal, reproduceable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem.  We simply can't answer your question unless we know EXACTLY what is going on, and the info you're providing is incomplete

Comment: It works fine for me - piecing together the bits of code you have in your question. The only thing I would point out is that the text you say is the table has a load of other stuff too - a couple of spans and the complete head and body as if it's a whole webpage you are getting not just the table.